# An error occurs when obfuscating the Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm about to release my Flutter app.

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

I read the above page and ran the following command in a terminal, but I get an error.

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info /projectName/odf
```

↓error contents

```
* Where:                                                                
Script '/Users/userno1/dev2/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1035
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.            
> Process 'command '/Users/userno1/dev2/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

---

```
flutter build appbundle
```

With the above command, the release build was successful.

I'd like to somehow obfuscate the source code, which is the result of my efforts.
Is there any good way?

Comment: postscript: First I ran "flutter build appbundle" to create the "build" directory, then I tried to obfuscate and ran "flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info /projectName/odf" and got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly using the command:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info /projectName/odf
```

because you're missing the `=` after `--split-debug-info`

Try the following command:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=your_debug_info_directory
```

Where `your_debug_info_folder` is a directory in your project

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added "=" and retry,but same error message appear.

Comment: make sure you have created the directory.

Comment: Yes, I created a new "/ projectroot / odf" directory and ran the command, but the result was the same. Thank you for your reply very much.

Comment: Try creating `debug_info` in your project directory, then try using the following command: `flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=debug_info` as it is.

Comment: When I did as you showed me
A success message is displayed, and it seems that it succeeded because files such as app.android-arm.symbols were generated in the "debug_info" directory.
I'm really thankful to you.
Anyway,
Is the description in the official documentation wrong?

Comment: The documentation is not wrong but a bit vague. the `/<project-name>/<directory>` is the absolute path to our project directory. When you're using `--split-debug-info=debug_info`, it means you're using the current directory as the relative path to `debug_info` directory.